# Ember.js Acceptance test not working if ember server not run

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js, gitlab, acceptance-testing

I'm trying to run `ember test`, when the ember server is running, everything is OK all my test pass !
When I don't execute ember server before (which is the case in my GitLab integration), I have one test which fail :

```
import { test } from 'qunit';
import moduleForAcceptance from 'emberjs-poc/tests/helpers/module-for-acceptance';

moduleForAcceptance('Acceptance | list rates');

test('visiting /rates', function(assert) {
  visit('/rates');

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/rates');
  });
});
```

I don't really understand why because in the `moduleForAcceptance` function we should run the app before each test.
I've this error for information :

```
Log: |
            { type: 'error',
              text: '\'Error while processing route: rates\' \'The adapter operation was aborted\'\n' }
            { type: 'error', text: 'null\n' }
```

The rate route :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.findAll('rate');
  }
});
```

The adapter :

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'rate',
  host: 'http://localhost:3000'
});
```

Comment: Are you doing anything custom in an adapter? What does the `rates` route look like?

Comment: @PatrickBerkeley I just have a RESTAdapter to call my api. I upload my post with the route.

Comment: are you mocking your backend, how does your model get its data/payload when in test mode?

Comment: I don't remember what I used to do, thank's anyway for your comment.